# joomla condition position module for content

Tags: joomla2.5

i create new template for j2.5,
i need to add many module only show on home,
now i need to show many module all page without home,
pleas see my code below :

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 co-md-12">

                            <?php if($this->countModules('adsright')) : ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="adsright" style="custom" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>     


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
        <div class="content">
                    <jdoc:include type="message" />
                    <jdoc:include type="component" /> </div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

when add module to adsright position and unchecked home page,was not show on my content,
how can i solve that ?
please tell me full way for create position conditional.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please give some clear description of your problem.

And if you want certain positions and div structure on home page and not require same on inner pages then you can set condition based on this code. I hope this will help.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'Home page';
}
```